# Get Grandchild Object Field Values from Parent Object

Tags: apex, soql, query, list

I'm a newbie at sales-force apex coding. I have 3 custom objects, **Location(Parent) -> Group(child) - > Meeting(grand child)**. All are related to each other through Master detail relationships. I am trying to get 2 field values from the earliest Meeting Record that belongs to the Location.

So far I managed to get the get 2 field values from the earliest Meeting Record that belongs to the Business Object.

```
public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 = [SELECT Name,
GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM    
Meeting__c WHERE Group__c =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c ASC LIMIT 1];
```

I am trying to get the same information obtained from the above query but this time I want to **get the earliest Meeting (grand child) Record that belongs to the Group records (child) belonging to the Location Record from the Location Object** *(Parent object getting grandchild record field values)*

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In SOQL only one level of parent-to-child relationship can be used in a query.
But we can achieve it from opposite direction i.e. child-to-parent.

Like we have three predefined object :-

```
   Opportunity
   Quote - Child
   QuoteLineItems - Grand Child
```

Now you can write a query like this:-

```
SELECT Id, Quantity, Quote.Name, Quote.Opportunity.Name FROM QuoteLineItem where Quote.Opportunity.Id = xyz
```